# How do you prove $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} = \frac{1}{e}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

prove the sum
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} = \frac{1}{e}$$

In one of the solutions to a problem I was looking at had this sum and directly got $1/e$ from it. I don't understand how you get that, I used my calculator and it indeed does equal $1/e$ but I'm interested in how you solve this by hand.

Comment: Use the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ and sub in $x = -1$.

Comment: Well, what is **your** definition of $\;e\;$ ? According to that it can be an almost trivial exercise or perhaps an even challenging one.

Comment: If you understand the problem statement, you must be aware of what $e$ is. If this is the case, you must also have heard of the series for $e^x$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, given that we know that

$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

we can put $x = -1$ to get the series, and the left hand side is then $e^{-1} = \frac{1}{e}$ by exponent rules.

However, perhaps that proof is not entirely satisfying: how do we know the exponent rules work for this series? We may not *know* yet it is an exponential function or that calling it $e^x$ is justified even if we may have reason to suspect it. Can we prove it without necessarily resorting to them?

Well, going on the supposition it *does* behave like an exponent, we may be tempted to multiply it with the series for $e$, if we have defined $e$ already by:

$$e = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$$

which gives

$$
\begin{align}
e \times ``\ e^{-1}" &= \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\right) \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \right) \\
&= \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} 1^n\right) \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} 1^n\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} 1^n \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} 1^k\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} 1^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} 1^k\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{n!k!} 1^{n+k}\\
&= \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n+k=l} \frac{(-1)^k}{n!k!} 1^l\\
&= \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{n+k=l} \frac{(-1)^k}{n!k!}\right) 1^l\\
&= \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{n+k=l} (-1)^k \frac{1}{l!} \frac{l!}{n!k!}\right) 1^l\\
&= \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{l!} \left(\sum_{n+k=l} {l \choose n, k} (-1)^k\right) 1^l\\
&= \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{l!} \left(\sum_{n+k=l} {l \choose n, k} 1^n (-1)^k\right) 1^l\\
&= \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{l!} (1 + (-1))^l 1^l\\
&= \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{l!} 0^l 1^l\\
&= 1
\end{align}
$$

where we used the multinomial theorem and that $0^0 = 1$ and $0! = 1$ but $0^l = 0$ for all $l > 0$. Thus the series must sum to the reciprocal of $e$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Exponential theorem,we get

$e^x=1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}\cdots\infty$
$\Rightarrow e^x=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$

Now if we put $x=-1$ then we get,$$e^{-1}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{{(-1)}^n}{n!}\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{e}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{{(-1)}^n}{n!}$$.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it directly from the definition of $e^x$:

$$e^x=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i!}$$

Comment: @Shashi; it's the one that kicks into complex numbers : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Complex_numbers, and equivalent to $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+1/n)^n$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x)= 1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} \dots \infty$$

$$f'(x)=0+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{2x}{2!}+\frac{3x^2}{3!}+\frac{4x^3}{4!} \dots \infty$$

$$f'(x)= 1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} \dots \infty$$

$$\implies f'(x)=f(x)$$

Whose general solution is $f(x)=e^x+c$, on comparing the value of $f(0)$, we get $c=0$.

Hence our function is:

$$f(x)=e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

What we want is ;

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}=f(-1)=e^{-1}$$

$$ \text{Therefore}~:~~\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} = \frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: Downvote from +1 to 0??Seriously?

Comment: The OP asking this question must be at a level such that he never heard about differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a new answer, just a more graphical illustration of the answer by @mike4ty4, too long for a comment.

Assuming that all you know is

$$e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!},$$

you can form the product

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}.$$

We arrange the pairwise products of the terms as a 2D array, of which we show the upper left corner. Notice the alternating signs.

$$\begin{matrix}\frac1{0!0!}&-\frac1{0!1!}&\frac1{0!2!}&-\frac1{0!3!}&\frac1{0!4!}&\cdots\\
\frac1{1!0!}&-\frac1{1!1!}&\frac1{1!2!}&-\frac1{1!3!}&\ddots\\
\frac1{2!0!}&-\frac1{2!1!}&\frac1{2!2!}&\ddots\\
\frac1{3!0!}&-\frac1{3!1!}&\ddots\\
\frac1{4!0!}&\ddots\\
\vdots\\
\end{matrix}$$

Then you can see a connection to Pascal's triangle, by multiplying every diagonal by the successive factorials, which gives integer numbers:

$$\begin{matrix}\frac{0!}{0!0!}&-\frac{1!}{0!1!}&\frac{2!}{0!2!}&-\frac{3!}{0!3!}&\frac{4!}{0!4!}&\cdots\\
\frac{1!}{1!0!}&-\frac{2!}{1!1!}&\frac{3!}{1!2!}&-\frac{4!}{1!3!}&\ddots\\
\frac{2!}{2!0!}&-\frac{3!}{2!1!}&\frac{4!}{2!2!}&\ddots\\
\frac{3!}{3!0!}&-\frac{4!}{3!1!}&\ddots\\
\frac{4!}{4!0!}&\ddots\\
\vdots\\
\end{matrix}$$

$$\begin{matrix}1&-1&1&-1&1&\cdots\\
1&-2&3&-4&\ddots\\
1&-3&6&\ddots\\
1&-4&\ddots\\
1&\ddots\\
\vdots\\
\end{matrix}$$

It turns out that the sum of every diagonal but the first is zero (this is a property of the binomial numbers, verified by expanding $(1-1)^n$), and this holds for the diagonals of the first array.

Hence

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}=1.$$